# Does Trigger iCloud Sync work with KVO on simulator

Tags: ios, icloud, key-value-observing

I'm trying to test with my simulator and real device, user-defaults modification via key-value storage in the iCloud.

Nothing is working but note that in [this][1] document

[1]: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html that there are some limitations. Namely, "iCloud document syncing and key-value storage support".

Does this mean it 100% doesn't work, or is it limited in what objects it can sync?

Thanks

Comment: iCloud only works on real devices.

Comment: Could someone offer a theory about why that is? For a max 1 Mb storage, I can't think why Apple would disallow key-value storage in the simulator. What is the technical limitation?